# \norm symbol have different sizes in equation

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

in the MWE below, the norm symbol appears in different sizes in the denominator like this:

[image]

I would like the `\norm` lines to be the same length in the denominator.  Thanks for your help.

Here is the code that I have:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \mu(\mathbf{A}) = \max_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n, i\neq j}\dfrac{|\mathbf{A'}_{:,i}\mathbf{A}_{:,j}|}{\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,i}}\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,j}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me guess it is autoscalling, as you can see not a good idea. It is probably the j that is causing it. I'd use mathtools to construct a better norm, it is on the manual.

Comment: The answer is very simple: don't use `commath`; look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=commath+user%3A4427 to see why.

Comment: It's a case for `\strut` or `\smash` or simply specifying the size explicitly with `\bigg` and the like. No need for package bloat.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the subscripts `i` and `j` have different depths and you are using automatic scaling.

There are two easy ways to fix this, since you are already using the `mathtools` and `commath` packages:

#### Solution with `mathtools` (preferred solution<sup>†</sup>)

Make the `\norm` symbols the same size by using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` to declare `\norm`, and give a size as an optional argument as `\norm[\big]{...}`. Since you are using the `commath` package, which itself defines `\norm`, you can "save" and "undefine" the old definition of `\norm` before (re)declaring it using `mathtools`. You should also place the prime outside of `\mathbf{...}`, otherwise the subscript is placed too far right.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\let\oldnorm\norm   % <-- Store original \norm as \oldnorm
\let\norm\undefined % <-- "Undefine" \norm
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \mu(\mathbf{A}) = \max_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n, i\neq j}\dfrac{|\mathbf{A}'_{:,i}\mathbf{A}_{:,j}|}{\norm[\big]{\mathbf{A}_{:,i}}\norm[\big]{\mathbf{A}_{:,j}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output with mathtools]

or without optional argument (most correct size in my opinion), i.e. with `{\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,i}}\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,j}}`:

[image: Best output]

#### Solution with `commath`

The `\norm` command from the `commath` also takes an optional argument, ranging from `0` to `4` where `0` is the smallest size and `4` the biggest. Notice how the spacing before the first `\norm` is wrong – you will have to manually adjust this with e.g. `\;` to get a pleasing result.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \mu(\mathbf{A}) = \max_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n, i\neq j}\dfrac{|\mathbf{A}'_{:,i}\mathbf{A}_{:,j}|}{\norm[1]{\mathbf{A}_{:,i}}\norm[1]{\mathbf{A}_{:,j}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output with commath]

---

You should consider using `\abs` instead of `|...|` as well.
Same approach as above with `mathtools`:

```
\let\oldabs\abs % Store original \abs as \oldabs
\let\abs\undefined % "Undefine" \abs
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

and then use `\abs*{...}` to get automatic sizing, or with optional argument to manually size `\abs[\big]{...}`.

For `commath` the approach is also the same as above: `\abs[1]{...}`.

---

<sup>†</sup>As you can see, the spacing before the first `\norm` in the denominator with `commath` (last image) is wrong, so personally I'd recommend using the `mathtools` approach, as that gives the correct spacing.

Answer (score 7):

A prime example why `\left` and `\right` should not be used without checking. I can't recommend using `commath` macros for several reasons, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=commath+user%3A4427 for some of them.

The problem of using `\left` and `\right` shows here in full clarity: the descender in `j` is the cause of the sudden growth of the delimiters' size.

Let's simplify the situation. Look at the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\left\|\mathbf{A}_{i}\right\|\ne
\left\|\mathbf{A}'_{i}\right\|\ne
\left\|\mathbf{A}_{j}\right\|\ne
\left\|\mathbf{A}'_{j}\right\|
\\
\left\|\mathbf{A}_{i}\right\|+\left\|\mathbf{A}_{j}\right\|
\\
\lVert\mathbf{A}_{i}\rVert+\lVert\mathbf{A}_{j}\rVert
\\
\left\|\mathbf{A}'_{i}\right\|+\left\|\mathbf{A}'_{j}\right\|
\\
\lVert\mathbf{A}'_{i}\rVert+\lVert\mathbf{A}'_{j}\rVert
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

and the output

[image]

Using `\left\|` and `\right\|` is basically the same as using `\norm` from `commath`.

You can notice that there are *three* delimiter sizes in line 1, two in lines 2 and 4. In particular, when `\mathbf{A}'_{j}` is used, the size is definitely too big.

It's clear to me that the “right” output is that in lines 3 and 5, with *no* size increase.

If you use `mathtools`, you can define a correct `\norm` macro and do manual adjustment *only when necessary*, which is not the case of your formula. I also suggest `\substack` for the long subscript.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mu(\mathbf{A}) =
\max_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n, i\neq j}
  \dfrac{|\mathbf{A'}_{:,i}\mathbf{A}_{:,j}|}
        {\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,i}}\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,j}}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mu(\mathbf{A}) =
\max_{\substack{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n \\ i\neq j}}
  \dfrac{|\mathbf{A'}_{:,i}\mathbf{A}_{:,j}|}
        {\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,i}}\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,j}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The size of the first \norm command doesn't correspond to any of the predefined sizes which can be used as an optional argument. So the only solution I can imagine is to `\smash` j:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \mu(\mathbf{A}) = \max_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n, i\neq j}\dfrac{|\mathbf{A'}_{:,i}\mathbf{A}_{:,j}|}{\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,i}}\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,\smash[b]{j}}}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could insert a strut into the first norm's index to make it taller:

```
\norm{\mathbf{A}_{:,i\mathstrut}}
```

A strut is a zero-width “letter” that extends as low and as high as any other letter. This forces the norm sign to be larger.

[image: equation with equal-sized bars]