# Warning when adding package minted?

Tags: warnings, minted, sharelatex

I am for some reason getting an warning when i try to load the package `minted` in sharelatex.

The warning is

```
Command \@parboxrestore has changed.

Package fvextra Warning: csquotes should be loaded after fvextra, to avoid a warning from the lineno package on input line 37.
```

I am not sure how i should interpret this?.. I've been very picky with my error messages, and trying avoid all kind of error messages, so why am I getting this warning when using `minted` in sharelatex, and how do i get rid of it?

Here is my preamble.tex

\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}

```
% ------- Enable UTF8 characters ------- %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{commath} % Added by Me - Used for norm
\usepackage{smartdiagram} % Added by Me - Smartdiagram 
\usepackage{glossaries} % Added by Me - Glossary
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\makeglossaries
%-------------- Glossary -----------------%
\input{glossaries/glossaries_entries.tex}
\glsaddallunused
% ------------ Code Listing ------------- %

\usepackage{minted}

% ------- Page layout ------- %
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref} % clickable references
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}

% ------- Images ------- %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\DeclareCaptionFont{gray}{\color{gray}}
%\captionsetup{textfont={footnotesize,sc,gray},font={footnotesize,sc,gray}}

\newcommand{\figscale}{0.7\linewidth}
\newcommand{\smallfigscale}{0.07\linewidth}

\usepackage{blindtext}



%References
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} %Natbib supports both [i] and Author (year) citation styles. \citet and \citep replace \cite.
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
%\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage[style=ieee,natbib=true,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,url=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography2.bib}




\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
%\usepackage[showframe,headsep=1cm,headheight=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[headsep=1cm,headheight=15pt]{geometry}

% Test

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,shadows.blur,positioning,calc,arrows.meta,automata}
\newcommand{\mx}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Matrix command
\newcommand{\vc}[1]{\mathbf{\bm{#1}}} % Vector command
\tikzstyle{pinkbox}=[draw,rounded corners,shade,top color=white,bottom color=pink,
                     minimum width=3.5cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center,node distance=1.5cm]
\tikzstyle{inter arrow}=[->,ultra thick,-{Triangle[angle=45:8pt]}]
```

Comment: Well, you're loading `csquotes` before `minted` (which in turn loads `fvextra`). Change the loading order. By the way, `hyperref` should be loaded last.

Comment: If I got your **problem** right, then you are searching for a solution for pasting '*Python code highlighted into a latech document*' which can be copied out of the PDF later on. As I could not get the minted package to work properly today (Windows, MiKTeX, TeXstudio), I found a different answer in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command()).
Take the answer of @redmode. The featured solution is lightweigt using environments leaving out 'extra packages' (=> no update-version-constraints).
Therefore it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `fvextra` package is loaded by `minted`, so you should load `minted` before `csquotes`.

Another thing you should do is loading `hyperref` last: very few packages should come later than this one and you are loading none of them.

<sub>Side note: `commath` is a very buggy package</sub>

Comment: Do you have an alternative to `commath`

Comment: @dfh https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297273/4427